# Large file uploads via WSHttpBinding in WCF

Tags: wcf, file-upload, wcf-binding

I'm working on a WCF file uploader using WSHttpBinding. I am looking to upload files around 10 mb (not playing an exact game on that one, but won't be getting files much larger). Everything works pretty well up to about 5mb. after that, I start getting HTTP 500 errors.

My binding is set up as follows:

```
wsBinding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
wsBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 52428800;
wsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 13631488;
wsBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
```

My httpRuntime maxRequestLength is 20480kb in web.config

My requests look like:

```
POST http://mywebsite/FileUploader.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://namespace/UploadPhoto"
Content-Length: 13979476
Host: mywebsite
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:fil="http://namespace">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://namespace/IFileUploaderSvc/UploadPhoto</wsa:Action></soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <fil:UploadPhoto>
         <fil:AuthorizationToken>(Password)</fil:AuthorizationToken>
         <fil:ProgramName>AProgram</fil:ProgramName>
         <fil:FileName>bigolefile.jpg</fil:FileName>
         <fil:File>(base 64 file data)</fil:File>
      </fil:UploadPhoto>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It is very important that I use WSHttpBinding, not WebHttpBinding.
Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: Do you have any config for your WCF service or is it configured and hosted via code? Also try enabling Tracing on your service to see why your upload fails for larger files : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Check this out: http://debugmode.net/2011/07/18/upload-large-file-of-size-more-than-5-mb-from-silverlight-to-server-location-using-wcf/. BasicHttpBinding is used there, but the article contains some information that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the TextMessageEncodingBindingElement or MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement for the messageEncoding property in WSHttpBinding binding.

For instance, the following snippet uses TextMessageEncodingBindingElement. **messageEncoding="Text"** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpWithMessageSecurity" messageEncoding="Text"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  textEncoding="utf-8"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
```